# How to Override Web Browser "Keyboard shortcut Ctrl-A is disabled"

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

Is there a way to override a web browser preventing me from using Ctrl-A to select all text in an editable input text box?

It is just annoying given that I need to select all the text so I can delete it and replace it with something else, so I end up having to scroll to the top, place the cursor there, then scroll to the bottom, press shift and click the last position to select it and then click delete.

[image]

I am using Chrome, but keyboard shortcut being disabled seems to be enforced by all browsers (I tried Firefox too).  I'm happy to use a different browser if there is a work around for a different browser.

Comment: the nerve of this web developer.. I am not allowed to (easily) select all the text in a friggen input box that I'm trying to fill out?!?! why would you ever want a keyboard shortcut to display an error message anyway?

Comment: Disabling JavaScript completely should do it but very likely the page depends on it. You can try killing the specific script if it is loaded from an external .JS using AdBlock or other techniques, or even [overriding](http://www.squakmt.com/replacing_javascript/index.htm) the specific JS function using GreaseMonkey.